# How to avoid the interruption of sleep calls due to a signal in Linux?

Tags: c, linux, signals

I'm using a real time signal in Linux to be notified of the arrival of new data in a serial port. Unfortunately this causes sleep calls to be interrupted when there is signal.

Does anybody know of a way to avoid this behavior?

I tried using a regular signal (SIGUSR1) but I keep getting the same behavior.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From the nanosleep manpage:

> nanosleep delays the execution of the program for at least the time specified in *req. The function can return earlier if a signal has been delivered to the process. In this case, it returns -1, sets errno to EINTR, and writes the remaining time into the structure pointed to by rem unless rem is NULL. The value of *rem can then be used to call nanosleep again and complete the specified pause.

Comment: I will go with this one. I gave a look inside the POCO libraries and their Thread::sleep implementation does something like you described.
Thanks

Comment: Don't forget to check your selected answer.

Comment: I won't but I prefer to wait a while before accepting an answer.

Comment: I found out that an interrupted `nanosleep()` on Linux sets `errno` to `ERESTARTSYS`, not to `EINTR`.  At least if a signal handler was installed using `sigaction()` with `SA_RESTART`.  It's not documented that way.

Answer (score 8):

You can mask almost all signals (except `SIGKILL`) using [`sigprocmask()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/sigprocmask) or [`signal()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/signal) calls. The first one will return you the previous mask, which you can recover after `sleep()`. Some examples are [here](http://users.evtek.fi/~tk/rtp/signals-programming.html). If that does not help, please, be more verbose of what signal interrupts your sleep. I think, you can additionally check this condition ("sleep interrupted by signal?") and fall into sleep again.

Comment: Your example link is broken.

Comment: Having the names of functions it is not difficult to find other examples, e.g. [Introduction To Unix Signals Programming](http://titania.ctie.monash.edu.au/signals/).

Answer (score 5):

Newer Linux kernels support [signalfd(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/signalfd). That, together with [sigprocmask(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/sigprocmask), is a very nice way to combine handling of signal and IO events in a single [epoll_wait(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/epoll_wait) call.

Comment: This is a really ugly and non-portable way to do something that's easily done with complete portability even to legacy systems (the self-pipe trick) or to all modern POSIX-conformant systems (with `pselect`).

Comment: Portability is an honorable, but not always the first, goal.

Comment: The only reason *not to* be portable in this instance is premature optimization, which is the root of all evil. There's a huge herd of Linux sheep proselytizing `epoll` for performance, whereas unless you're handling hundreds of thousands of file descriptors at a time, plain `poll` will never be your bottleneck (and even then it almost surely won't be). Don't drink the koolaid.

Comment: OK, I'll happily leave the herd if you point me to a portable way of waiting on both file descriptors *and* signals (and note that I wasn't talking about performance :).

Comment: The classic way that works on all legacy systems is to have your signal handler do nothing but write a single byte to a pipe, and include the read end of the pipe in your `fd_set` for `select`. Or if you're happy depending on POSIX, you can keep signals blocked and use `pselect` to unblock them atomically during the `pselect` wait. Then you can just check for global flags set by the signal handlers after `pselect` returns to see which signal was received. Note that if you use plain `select` and unblock/block signals yourself, there is a serious race condition where signals will be missed.

Comment: Yes, the old self-pipe trick, right. Wouldn't it be nice not to cross user/kernel line four times?

Comment: If you really care, use `pselect`. But if signals are a frequent occurrence, then you probably have a major design flaw to begin with...

Comment: Yes, you probably are right. Though I don't believe there is single "right" way of doing everything.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to be interrupted, why are you using the real time signal?

Somewhere, either in Rockind's "Advanced Unix Programming" or Steven's book, there was an example of how to fake this out.  You make note of the current time_t before starting your sleep.  After the sleep ends, you check to make sure the required amount of time has elapsed, and if it hasn't, you start a new sleep.  Put the sleep in a loop that calculates the time to go and sleeps that amount, and exits when the required time has passed.

Comment: There are all kinds of problems related to this if the system clock changes. That's why POSIX provides much more sophisticated clock functions than just the `sleep` call, which should probably be completely abandoned...

Answer (score 2):

Well, a realtime signal is supposed to interrupt sleep.  You could use a non-realtime signal instead.  Another approach is to check if the expected time to sleep has elapsed, and if not, sleep for the remaining interval.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but using a regular signal also interrupts sleep calls.