# Using processes to count number of files

Tags: c, process

I wrote the program which main goal is to count number of files that are located in the directory (and all the subdirectories). Program should create new process every time, it searches new directory. So basically one process per directory.

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    //if wSwtich is set to 1 each process will sleep
    int wSwitch = 0;

   if(getenv("MASTER_OF_PIDS")==NULL)
{
    char *toPass = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*10);
    sprintf(toPass,"%ld",(long)getpid());
    setenv("MASTER_OF_PIDS",toPass,1);
}

    char *w = "-w";
    if (argc > 1)
    {
        if (strcmp(argv[1], w) == 0)
        {
            printf("Switch -w set to on \n");
            wSwitch = 1;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("No additional options enabled \n");
    }

    DIR *dir;
    struct dirent *entry;
    struct stat info;
    char * path;
    int counter = 0;
    int files  = 0;
    int childProcesses = 0;
    pid_t pid;

    //checking if path_to_browse was set
    if((path=getenv("PATH_TO_BROWSE"))==NULL)
    {
        path = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*512);
        strcpy(path,"./");
    }

    //getting the current dir
    dir = opendir(path);
    if (dir == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error while getting acces to directory ! \n");
        _exit(1);
    }

    while ((entry = readdir(dir)) != NULL)
    {
        char *name = entry->d_name;

        //have to check if this is current directory if so move on

        if(strcmp(name,".")==0 || strcmp(name,"..") == 0 || strcmp(name," ") == 0)
        {
            continue;
        }

        //checking if file i a regular one, if so increase the counter and continue
        if (entry->d_type == DT_REG)
        {
            counter = counter + 1;
            printf("File: %s counter: %d\n",name,counter);
            continue;
        }

        //checking if it is a dir, if so fork and search
        if(entry->d_type == DT_DIR)
        {
            char nextPath[512];
            strcpy(nextPath,path);
            strcat(nextPath,"/");
            strcat(nextPath,entry->d_name);

            //setting the PATH_TO_BROWSE
            //last argument is overwriting
            setenv("PATH_TO_BROWSE",nextPath,1);

            printf("Directory: %s \n",nextPath);
            childProcesses++;
            pid = fork();
            if(pid<0)
            {
                printf("Error ! \n");
                _exit(1);
            }

            int errorChecker = 1;
            if(pid==0)
            {
                if(wSwitch)
                {
                    errorChecker = execlp(argv[0],argv[0],"-w",NULL);
                }
                else
                {
                    errorChecker = execlp(argv[0], argv[0], NULL);
                }
            }

            if(errorChecker == -1)
            {
                printf("Error ! \n");
                _exit(1);
            }
        }
    }

    if(wSwitch)
    {
        printf("I am in the switch! \n");
        sleep(5);
    }

    int status;
    while(childProcesses--)
    {
        wait(&status);
        files += WEXITSTATUS(status);
    }

if(atoi(getenv("MASTER_OF_PIDS"))==getpid())
{
    printf("Counter: %d \n",files + counter);
    return 0;
}
    _exit(counter + files);
}
```

Program succeed in searching all directories and subdirectories correctly identifying files.

My problems:

1. sleep(5)` has no effect. I have no idea why
2. <s>Each process correctly sum the number of the files, but at the end, how to sum them all and output?</s>
3. <s>My program is never ending (I think it is because I am not sending `return 0`) How to end this program correctly?</s>

Solution of problem 1:
[How to avoid the interruption of sleep calls due to a signal in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2223742/how-to-avoid-the-interruption-of-sleep-calls-due-to-a-signal-in-linux)

Comment: I solved problem 2 and 3. But still sleep has no effect

Comment: Note that the exit status can at most return 255; if you have big directories, the scheme counting files via exit statuses is doomed to failure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might not be getting the behavior you expect because of the interaction between wait() and sleep() - [see docs for details.](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/sleep.html)

Specifically note:

> until either the number of realtime seconds specified by the argument seconds has elapsed **or a signal is delivered to the calling thread and its action is to invoke a signal-catching function** or to terminate the process

Comment: I see, is there a way to prevent this? Or how to make this sleep uninterruptible ?

Comment: Ok I found the solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2223742/how-to-avoid-the-interruption-of-sleep-calls-due-to-a-signal-in-linux